# What is the name of a dish where meat is doused with brandy and lit on fire?

Tags: beef, food-identification, flambe

In about 1972 as a new bride, I made something with beef in the oven (had to have been from a cookbook) and then poured brandy over it and lit it on fire before serving.  As we were college students, it would not have been an expensive cut of meat.  I have searched using words like beef, brandy, flambee, fire, etc. but come up blank. Does anyone recognize the dish? Would love to serve it for our 45th anniversary next month!

Answer (score 4):

**Steak Diane**

I first had Steak Diane at the Brown Palace in Denver long ago. I have made it several times and found the brandy flavor is overwhelmed by the other flavors.

If you want the liquor flavor, I have found a smoked or grilled Bourbon Chicken on Food TV that has a lot of flavor. The chicken is brined overnight in soy sauce  brown sugar and bourbon, etc. but doesn't include flambe. Chicken might not be festive enough for your anniversary, though, but congratulations.

Comment: Definitely. Steak Diane was trendy in the 1970s.

Comment: This sounds like interesting inspiration for a faux-meat steak ... some flavor layering going on there ...